# Lock excel sheets based on checkboxes

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have a series of excel workbooks with sheets for each month in them to track data. The names of each month are fixed and locked in each of the workbooks.

I have a MasterKey.xlsm file that I'm using to automatically lock/unlock the sheets so that the admins of them can gain full access. I would like to add to this MasterKey sheet the function of locking months after they have passed.

I would like a checkbox block for each month

O Jan

O Feb

O Mar

...

So that the admin can review the previous month and then lock the sheet.

I've never used checkboxes before so if anyone can steer me in the right direction for a checkbox driven macro that will read the value of each checkbox and then I can add my lock script in after it for each selected unit that would be great.

Comment: Are the check boxes in a user form? Or in the workbook?

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a listbox with these property settings: `ListStyle = fmListStyleOption` and `MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti`.

[image]

Select your MasterKey worksheet. Then run **SetupListboxLockWorkSheets** one time. It will add a listbox to the ActiveSheet and configure it for you.

```
    Sub SetupListboxLockWorkSheets()

        Dim ListBox As MSForms.ListBox
        Dim ws As Worksheet

        Set ListBox = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ListBox.1", Link:=False, _
            DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=48.75, Top:=29.25, Width:=150, Height:=200).Object

        ListBox.Name = "lboLockSheets"

        ListBox.ListStyle = fmListStyleOption
        ListBox.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            If Not ws.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then ListBox.AddItem ws.Name

        Next

    End Sub
```

In the MasterKey code module add this code

```
Private Sub lboLockSheets_Change()
    Const PASSWORD As String = "password"
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With lboLockSheets.Object

        Dim text As String

        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            Set ws = Worksheets(.List(i))
            If .Selected(i) Then

                ws.Protect PASSWORD

            Else

               ws.Unprotect PASSWORD
            End If
        Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How about if I wanted to let them check as many boxes as they like and then run a macro that is a loop of if tests:  for Jan to Dec, if cbJan=true, lock cbJan, loop...